# Hosts file entry returns 404 Not Found

Tags: hosts, staging

In the past when I migrated a site I setup a host with my domain, update my hosts file with the domain and new IP address and start migrating assets.  My issue is that now when I try this I get an invalid SSL certificate and when continuing go to a 404 page.

What has changed over the past year or so since my last migration? and any advice on setting up a staging environment these days if this no longer works due to updates to security in browsers/etc?

EDIT:
I am using a shared host (Hostgator) for the new sites location and have everything setup besides pointing DNS.  Instead of pointing my domain to the new shared host I updated my Hosts file.  I am going to do a lot of modification before switching DNS from the live site to the one on Hostgator.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. What kind of server? Is this local? Do you have a hosting provider?

Comment: I have added an edit but basically I have a copy of my site on Hostgator and to avoid interfering with the live site I just updated my hosts file with my domain and the Hostgator IP address.  I have done this 100 times in the past but it is no longer working for me these days.